# Toggling a tkinter window open using shortcut

Tags: python, tkinter, window, toggle, python-3.7

I am far from an experience programmer/scriptor and this is my first project containing UI (tkinter).

I have a key on my keyboard bind to a function to open a window.
I am using something like this to bind it to the key:

```py
root.bind('<s>', popupmsg)
```

This is the function I'm calling:

```py
def popupmsg(msg):
    global MSGroot
    MSGroot = Tk()

    lab1.config("test")
    lab1= Label(MSGroot, font=('times', 40), bg='blue', fg="red")
    lab1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    MSGroot.title("TIME")
    MSGroot.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
    MSGroot.mainloop()
```

**This code works** and displays the window just fine however I would like to find an elegant way to simply toggle that window on and off using the same key binding.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

**There are many suggestions that I would make, that would make your code nicer/more elegant.**

> Firstly, do not use a `Tk()` window for a popup window, use a
>   `TopLevel()` window, two `Tk()` windows cannot pass information
>   between each other, so use a `TopLevel()` window instead.

```py
def popupmsg(msg):
        global MSGroot
        MSGroot = TopLevel(root) # needs the main Tk() window as a master/parent element

        lab1.config("test")
        lab1= Label(MSGroot, font=('times', 40), bg='blue', fg="red")
        lab1.grid(row=0, column=1) 

        MSGroot.title("TIME")
        MSGroot.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
```

> Secondly, you should create classes to make your `Tk` and
>   `TopLevel` windows, this just formats your code better, and is more
>   functional for making changes to how windows work.

```py
class PopUpMsg(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master, msg):
        super(PopUpMsg, self).__init__(master)

        lab1 = Label(self, font=('times', 40), bg='blue', fg="red")
        lab1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.title("TIME")
        self.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')


# This is now the function you could use to show the popup
def popupmsg(msg): 
    test_popup = PopUpMsg(root, msg) # This is how you would create the PopUpMsg
    test_popup.pack()


root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

> Lastly to make it so then the window will close when you press "s"
>   again I would make an `on_close` method of this new `PopUpMsg` class,
>   and bind "s" to it.

```py
class PopUpMsg(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(PopUpMsg, self).__init__(master)

        lab1 = Label(self, font=('times', 40), bg='blue', fg="red")
        lab1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.title("TIME")
        self.bind('<s>', self.on_close)

    def on_close(self):
        self.destroy()
```

Comment: You should normally not call `mainloop` more than once.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for the pickup, forgot to remove that line

Comment: Thanks a lot for the knowledge! I was not aware of some best practices and I am new to this this is extremely helpful. will come back here if I fail to implement this.
cheers